# "toHaveStyle" does not work on Jest (React Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs

I would like to understand (and pass the test) why whenever I'm attempting to use "toHaveStyle" I receive this following answer:
"received value must be an HTMLElement or an SVGElement.
Received has type:  object
Received has value: {}".

I am using React with Typescript here is my config:

```
//structure
-frontend
 -node_modules
 -src
   -component
   -setupTests.ts
   -App.tsx
   -etc
 -babel.config.js
 -jest.config.js
 -package.json
 -tsconfig.json

//package.json
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"test:coverage": "react-scripts test --coverage --runInBand --watchAll=false",
 }
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.12.1",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
"@types/jest": "^26.0.14",
"jest": "^26.5.3",
"ts-jest": "^26.4.1",
"@types/enzyme": "^3.10.7",
"@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.6",
"@types/jsdom": "^16.2.4",
"enzyme": "^3.11.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
"eslint": "^7.9.0",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.1.1",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.1.1",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
"prettier": "^2.1.2"
}


//jest.config.js
module.exports = {
preset: 'ts-jest',
snapshotSerializers: ['enzyme-to-json/serializer'],
testEnvironment: 'node',
transform: {
'^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
},
"testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(js|ts|tsx)?$",
moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts'],
collectCoverage: true,
transformIgnorePatterns: ["[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"]
};

//setupTests.ts
import enzyme from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

//ts.config.json
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
"allowJs": true,
"skipLibCheck": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"isolatedModules": true,
"jsx": "react",
"strict": true,
"noEmit": true, // we don't need to generate files as react works directly
"types": [
  "jest",
  "node",
  "react"
] },
"include": ["src"],
"exclude": ["./node_modules", "*.js"]
}

//babel.config.js
module.exports = {
presets: [
['@babel/preset-env', {targets: {node: 'current'}}],
+ '@babel/preset-typescript',
],
};

//Burger.tsx


import React from "react";
import "./burger.css";

//clickEvent
type Props = {
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
clickEvent: Function;
isItClicked: boolean;
};
const Burger: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
// eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
const { clickEvent, isItClicked } = props;

return (
<div
 data-testid="no-classes"
  id="burger"
  onClick={() => clickEvent()}
  className={isItClicked ? "cross" : ""}
 >
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
);
};

export default Burger;

//burger.css
#burger {
position: absolute;
}

//burger.test.js
import * as React from 'react';
import Burger from "../Burger.tsx"
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

describe("We test the innerHTML of the burger", () => {
let wrapper;
beforeEach(() => {
wrapper = mount(<Burger />);
});
test("Snapshot burger ", () => {
//It works
expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
test("burger style css", () => {
//it doesn't work
expect(wrapper.find("#burger")).toHaveStyle('position: absolute')
});  
});
```

I would like to clarify that my snapshot works. Thank you very much for any investigations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` returns Enzyme wrapper object that can contain multiple elements.

For a matcher that expects DOM element, it can be:

```
expect(wrapper.find("#burger").getDOMNode()).toHaveStyle('position: absolute')
```

Comment: I do not have anymore the kind of result that I used to but my test is not valid yet. Now, the result of my test has muted to: 
expect(element).toHaveStyle()
    - Expected
    - position: absolute;
test("Burger style css", () => {

  expect(wrapper.find("#burger").getDOMNode()).toHaveStyle('position: absolute')                                                                         
 });  });
However, it's a good step forward. Thank you.

Comment: CSS are commonly stubbed in Jest tests. This may be the case for your setup, although I don't see anything related to .css in your config. It should have been result in syntax error on import without additional transforms because CSS isn't valid JS.

Comment: When I add CSS directly in my component my test passes (<Burger style={{position: "absolute"}}>. But, when CSS is imported as you said, no. I will have to find out how to consider .css files in my config. Thank you very much.